# Storing of technical developer data

Tags: database, php, .net

I am looking for a webapplication to store the technical data for our clients (we are a big company that creates websites and webapplications for clients) This is currently solved by a web application we made ourself but we don't want to keep developing on this.

The structure we have now is like this:

[image]

Per environment you can add stuff like:

- user credientals,
- FTP servers,
- Server details,
- etc..

So we now want a solution made by someone, who is not us, that maintains it.

The price is not really important also the requierements (PHP, .NET, NodeJS) are not really important. We are just looking for a fitting solution.

It should be very configurable and also be extendible (we might want to add some functionality)